# Why is AWS CodePipeline complaining about 'Dockerfile' and 'Dockerrun.aws.json'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am creating a **CodePipeline** for my application, but the deployment process for **AWS ElasticBeanstalk** is failing with the following error:

> Instance deployment: Both 'Dockerfile' and 'Dockerrun.aws.json' are
> missing in your source bundle. Include at least one of them. The
> deployment failed.

**The complete message error is:**

> Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment,
> some instances may have deployed the new application version. To
> ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the
> appropriate application version. Failed to deploy application.
> Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s)
> 'i-0b8823de2e7376c81'. Aborting the operation. [Instance:
> i-0b8823de2e7376c81] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1
> Output: Engine execution has encountered an error.. Instance
> deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'. Instance
> deployment: Both 'Dockerfile' and 'Dockerrun.aws.json' are missing in
> your source bundle. Include at least one of them. The deployment
> failed.

My environment has 3 containers and to deploy this environment I use the **docker-compose-qa.yml** file and in **AWS CodeBuild** I'm defining this file as an artifact, as shown below:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - 'docker-compose-qa.yml'
```

The **docker-compose-qa.yml**:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

    sitr-api:
        image: ${{ secrets.SITR_API_QA_URI_DOCKER_IMG }}
        container_name: sitr-api-qa
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=QA
        ports:
            - "9901:80"
        volumes:
            - "./Host-Logs:/app/App_Data/Logs"

    sitr-app:
        image: ${{ secrets.SITR_APP_QA_URI_DOCKER_IMG }}
        container_name: sitr-app-qa
        ports:
            - "9902:80"
    
    sitr-nginx: 
        image: ${{ secrets.SITR_NGINX_QA_URI_DOCKER_IMG }}
        container_name: sitr-nginx-qa
        depends_on: 
          - sitr-app
          - sitr-api
        ports: 
          - "80:80"
```

**eb-engine.log error:**

> 2021/10/26 22:07:27.977004 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution
> of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop
> running the command. Error: Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json are both
> missing, abort deployment
>
> 2021/10/26 22:07:27.977008 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic 2021/10/26
> 22:07:27.977098 [INFO] CommandService Response:
> {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine
> execution has encountered an
> error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment: Both
> 'Dockerfile' and 'Dockerrun.aws.json' are missing in your source
> bundle. Include at least one of them. The deployment
> failed.","timestamp":1635286047,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance
> deployment failed. For details, see
> 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1635286047,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

My **CodeBuild** just build a **dotnet application**, **angular aplication** and build the **3 docker containers** for both application and nginx.

If I run my CodeBuild manually and then choose my **docker-compose-qa.yml** file in AWS EB, the publication is successfully applied.

I checked AWS S3 Bucket and the file is being zipped to a folder for the artifact.

**The question is:**

Why is Pipeline complaining about the non-existence of **'Dockerfile'** and **'Dockerrun.aws.json'** files? How can I specify it to use the **docker-compose-qa.yml** file?

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details. What exactly is your EB platform? How did you define your CodeBuild. Not sure what CodeDeploy has anything to do with that?

Comment: @Marcin my **CodeBuild** just build a **dotnet application**, **angular aplication** and build the **3 docker containers** for both application and nginx. I edited the question in more detail but if I need the full CodeBuild I can post in the question.

Comment: You wrote " in AWS CodeDeploy I'm defining this file as an artifact, as shown below"? I guess it should be CodeBuild? Also you must rename `docker-compose-qa.yml` into `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: It should be called `docker-compose.yml`, not `docker-compose-qa.yml`.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for the comment about " in AWS CodeDeploy I'm defining this file as an artifact, as shown below". I made the correction. I'm running a deploy with the file renamed.

Comment: So the deployment worked?

Comment: @Marcin It just finished, it worked yes, it was just the name of the file! If you can post as an answer, I accept it here! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **wrong file name**. It should be called `docker-compose.yml`, not `docker-compose-qa.yml`. Renaming the file solved the issue.